# How to call a Java method in AJAX?

Tags: java, ajax, web

I want to know how can I call a Java method or a Java class through AJAX 
ie `xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);` what is the code that I should write in place of URL that it should call a specific Java method in which my query is written

Comment: Map that url to a servlet. Put that code in servlet. Return from there.

Comment: [How to use Servlets and Ajax?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4113258/1391249). It is about using JSON.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use Servlets and Ajax?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112686/how-to-use-servlets-and-ajax)